# fxHide and fxShow doesn't seem to be working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but the fxHide and fxShow don't work in @angular/flex-layout.

```
<p fxHide> Start editing to see some magic happen :) </p>
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
"@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^9.1.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
"@angular/core": "^9.1.9",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31"
```

Here's a Stackblitz [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hwwii1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) for reference.

Comment: please find the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import FlexLayoutModule with FlexModule in your appmodule. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Import FlexLayoutModule in your app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FlexModule, FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
      BrowserModule, 
      FormsModule, 
      FlexModule, 
      FlexLayoutModule, 
      CommonModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```